# How do I disable Multibyte string input conversion in PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I am attempting to install `Drupal 7` on my local `debian jessie` machine, and it is telling me the following:

> Multibyte string input conversion in PHP is active and must be
> disabled. Check the php.ini mbstring.http_input setting. Please refer
> to the PHP mbstring documentation for more information.

Ok, so I head over to the [php documentation linked in that message](https://www.php.net/mbstring) and it provides me with a lot of (helpful, I am sure) information not at all related to disabling "Multibyte string input conversion". If it's there, I didn't find it.

I googled and came up with [a thread on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/132723), which claims:

> Since Drupal made it mandatory to disable mbstring.http_input and its
> 'relatives', a lot complaints regarding Drupal installation was raised
> everywhere in cyberspace. It's not a problem if you own your own
> server, and there's a lot of workaround.

And [provides a link](https://www.drupal.org/node/87138) to a page that I add the following to my `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value mbstring.http_input pass
php_value mbstring.http_output pass
```

So I had a look in my `.htaccess` file and found this:

```
# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.                                                        
<IfModule mod_php5.c>                                                           
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off                                 
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off                                 
  php_flag register_globals                 off                                 
  php_flag session.auto_start               off                                 
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass                                
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass                                
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off                                 
</IfModule>
```

Right, so now what?

**EDIT:** Just added the following line to my php.ini file:

> mbstring.http_input = pass    ; No conversion.

and ran `service apache2 reload`. No effect.

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue as of Drupal 7.33 https://www.drupal.org/node/2332295#comment-9301965

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Added the following to my `php.ini` file:

```
mbstring.http_input = pass ;
mbstring.http_output = pass ;
```

then I ran

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

And then I could install drupal manually, however, if I try using `drush` I still get the error, so this is really just half a solution...

Comment: If you get the error when installing with drush then you probably have different PHP settings for the command line. You can run `php --ini` from the command line to see which .ini files are loaded.

Answer (score 4):

Instead you can edit your site's `.htaccess` file or `settings.php` file to do so.

This way there will not be any conflict between your site and your drush configuration. And in case you changed your server's php version in the future, you don't have to re-do the same changes to the new  php version's `php.ini` file.

Via `.htaccess`:

```
php_value mbstring.http_input pass
php_value mbstring.http_output pass
```

Or via settings.php:

```
ini_set('mbstring.http_input', 'pass');
ini_set('mbstring.http_output', 'pass');
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable mbstring function overloading without disabling mbstring, you have to use

```
mbstring.func_overload = 0
```

This can be set in the php.ini file, and if not set there, in the vhost setting or .htaccess.

If it does not work, try looking for an mbstring.ini file, for example in /etc/php.d/mbstring.ini. This gets loaded after php.ini, and will override any value set there.

You may also need to add the following, however this is already set in Drupal's htaccess file, so if this file is being loaded correctly there should be no change.

```
php_value mbstring.http_input pass
php_value mbstring.http_output pass
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, installing `php-mbstring` module helped to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

the same error here with the installation of a drupal demo
but I realised that the site has no .htaccess file 
I copied one into the site 
and the problem disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment `extension=php_mbstring.dll` in **php.ini** file and restart apache

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is asking you to enable the mbstring (multibyte string), but your default php settings has this option disabled. If you can change your php.ini file to enable this, then your problem will be fixed, but sometimes we don't have access to that file.

Instead, we can set drupal to enable this option only for this particular site. On your sites/default/settings.php file (or the respective copy you may be using), add this:

ini_set('mbstring.http_input', 'pass');

ini_set('mbstring.http_output', 'pass');

and reload your php

This will set the mbstring option for this particular drupal site. If this still fails, it may be possible that your server's php does not have mbstring installed at all. Run phpinfo() in your browser and search for a mbstring section. If you don't find it at all, then you need to install it or ask a server administrator to do it for you